# Disable ONLY horizontal scroll on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, scroll

I want to block scrolling from left to right (horizontal) on a website viewed on a iPad/iPhone. But scroll from top to bottom (vertical) has to be enabled.

No result with CSS:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

You can still scroll on the iPad.

Javascript  `document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }`                     blocks all scrolling: horizontal and vertical.

I need a solution to block or disable ONLY the horizontal scrolling. Is that possible?

Comment: where do you add `overflow-x: hidden;` ?

Comment: In the html. Also tried it in de body. But it's not the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can use:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: The CSS overflow property isn't a solution for iPad. It works fine for browsers on pc, not for Safari on iPad.